# apache нету httpd.conf,как запустить php файлы

Tags: php, c#, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Я делал привязку по железу, с c#,php и базой данных,клиент отправлял запрос php файл его обрабатывал и проверял есть ли в базе данных пользователь в качестве сервера у меня vds(debian)
та строка по идеи должна отправлять запрос на сервер что бы получить от него ответ в php файле

```
    string rsp = req.Post("http://host-95-142-47-19.hosted-by-vdsina.ru/phpmyadmin/index.php?", data).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(rsp);
```

Я эти php файлы должен был определить на сервер,установил apache2 в файле httpd.conf нужно настроить директории папке с файлами php что бы при запросе.
Получать ответ а не это
[image: Получать ответ а не это]

httpd.conf файла нету,в место него apache2,conf
Я без понятия как решить эту проблему

Вот вам код php и c#

класс {getdata}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Management;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace IronPythonApplication1a
{
    class GetData
    {
    public static string`введите сюда код` GetMd5(string data)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider csp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] byteHash = csp.ComputeHash(bytes);

            string hash = "";

            foreach (byte b in byteHash)
                hash += $"{b:x2}";

            return hash.ToUpper();
        }

        public static string GetHwid() => 
            (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_processor").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                                           select x.GetPropertyValue("ProcessorId")).First().ToString();

        public static string GetUserOs() => 
            (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                                           select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First().ToString();

        public static string GetHddSerial() => 
            (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                                           select x.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber")).First().ToString();

        public static string GetMacAdress() => NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
         .First(x => x.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString() != string.Empty).GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

    }
}
```

форма

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using xNet;

namespace IronPythonApplication1a
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Active_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(login.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pass.Text))
                return;
            string sign = $"ShockByte-{GetData.GetUserOs()}-{login.Text}-{GetData.GetHwid()}-ShockByte";
               sign = GetData.GetMd5(sign);

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            RequestParams data = new RequestParams();
            data["login"] = login.Text;
            data["password"] = pass.Text;
            data["hwid"] = sign;

            string rsp = req.Post("http://host-95-142-47-19.hosted-by-vdsina.ru/phpmyadmin/index.php?", data).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(rsp);

        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'globals.php'

if($_POST['login'] == null || $_POST['password'] == null || $_POST['hwid'] ==  null)
    die();

$controller = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

$u_login = $_POST['login'];
$u_password = $_POST['password'];
$u_hwid = $_POST['hwid'];

$rsp = $controller->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$u_login' AND password='$u_password'");
if(@rsp->num_rows == 0)
    die("2");

$u_data = $rsp->fetch_assoc();
$id = $u_data['id'];
$db_hwid = $u_data['hwid'];

if($db_hwid == null){
    $controller->query("UPDATE users SET hwid='WHERE' id='$id'");
    die("3");
}

if($db_hwid != $u_hwid)
    die("4");

die("1");
```

globals.php

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST","localhost");
    define("DB_LOGIN","данные");
    define("DB_PASSWORD","данные");
    define("DB_NAME","данные");
```

Comment: Как вам угодно.

Comment: снял минус. почитал. во-первых, вам стоит уточнить url, потому что у вас по указанному адресу открывается админка phpmysqladmin, а не ваш код. возможно проблема не в конфиг-файле httpd вообще и когда поправите url то этого будет достаточно. во-вторых, *nix-системы которые вы упомянули имеют одинаковый формат и httpd.conf мало чем отличается от apache2.conf В-третьих, приведенный код c# и php выглядит вполне рабочим, дело на текущем этапе не в нём совершенно. Вероятнее всего вам нужно создать конфигурационный файл вашего виртуального хоста, а также перевесить phpmyadmin на другой порт.